# Is «ado» used often?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary, phrases

The following expression seems to be quite common:

> *without further ado*

Despite “ado” is a word with its own meaning I do not hear native speakers use it much separately. Is it the word that is mostly used   only as a part of the phrase?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The word "ado" is an example of an archaic word surviving as part of familiar idioms. "Without further ado" is a fairly common expression, as is "much ado about nothing", which is the title of a Shakespeare play, and most native speakers are familiar with these expressions. Beyond these idioms, the word "ado" in isolation isn't used much at all. Some comments to this answer have suggested that the word might be used in some regional British dialects, but in other English speaking countries, it is not used at all. As a native British English speaker myself, I haven't heard it used outside of the two idioms but evidently, in some remoter regions, it might be.

A similar word "to-do" (meaning more worry/work than ought to be necessary) is used a little more in British English, and you will find a few more modern examples using it. This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an%20ado%2C%20a%20to-do&smoothing=3&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20ado%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20to%20-%20do%3B%2Cc0) compares the use of "a to-do" and "an ado" in literature.

Comment: if you said "I tried to transfer the registration of my second car to my daughter but it involved so much ado that I left it until after my holiday', nobody would turn a hair, at least in Britain.

Comment: However, in many parts of Australia and America, and with many people, you’d definitely be laughed at, so be cautious, @UntappedSoul

Comment: @MichaelHarvey At least in Alberta, Canada, and I expect all of the English speaking part of the country, I'm pretty sure that using «ado» this way would be rare to the point of nonexistence. «To-do» would, I think, be understood, although I would probably use either «fuss» or «hassle» if I wasn't being intentionally slightly old fashioned.

Comment: "So much ado for what?" - negative Trip advisor review of a London bar. "So much ado over a few crumbs of bread... Fish in a pond in the Alcázar gardens in Sevilla, all fighting for food people are throwing into the water" "In our hypochondriac age, a great deal of ado has been made over the unhealthy state of contemporary American humor." "A great deal of ado has been made about how the Lions and Colts played a great deal of man coverage against the Chiefs"

Comment: @Fivesideddice - I didn't get where I am today by worrying about what ignorant people laugh at, whether in Australia, America, or anywhere else.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I'm British and I would defintely turn a hair - I'd think you'd said "ado" instead of "to-do".

Comment: People who I talk to pretty soon get the idea that when I say something, I mean to say it, and that I generally have a good reason to do so. My wife is from Lancashire, and she says 'ado' is a pretty everyday word there. I 've heard it myself when I've been to Wigan with her.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I'm from Lancashire, my wife is from Yorkshire. People from Lancashire do say "what a to-do!". In 45 years of living in Lancashire I have never heard anyone say "what an ado!"

Comment: Maybe it's very local to Swinley

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I’m just warning the OP; it’s good to fit with the social context wherever you are. Say ‘ado’ in Britain whenever you like, but don’t say it in Australia if you want to be taken seriously by *everyone*.

Comment: [contemporary example](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/2642024) not (quite) using the idiom:  'When he finally sits down, he plays with his food or throws it across the room. But last night he ate his dinner without much ado ..."

Comment: @mcalex I've added in some substance from your comments and those of others, and also included an ngram comparison.

Comment: @Fivesideddice - I don't have any plans to go to Australia any time soon.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That’s really not the point; I’m adding a note of warning to your caveat to Astralbee’s excellent answer, in the hope that if the OP takes your advice, they don’t expand it to the general case; in the hope that they will be *cautious*. It isn’t directed at you, and I don’t want to have a fight in the comments about this.